# tensorflow: convert scalar tensor to python scalar object in graph

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to convert scalar tensor (`tf.constant([4])` for example) to python scalar (4) inside a computational graph so without use `tf.eval()`.

Comment: When you say convert to python scaler inside the computational graph, only tensor can exist inside the computational graph. Could you maybe provide a code example showing what your after?

Answer (score 1):

Constant values are hardwired into the graph, so you can see it by inspecting graph definition.

IE

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.constant(42)
print tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
```

This gives you

```
node {
  name: "Const"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_INT32
        tensor_shape {
        }
        int_val: 42
      }
    }
  }
}
versions {
  producer: 9
}
```

This means you can get the constant value out as

```
tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node[0].attr["value"].tensor.int_val[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Session.run() method.

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [3]: x = tf.constant(4)

In [4]: sess.run(x)
Out[4]: 4
```